# Unable to connect a SSL\TLS encrypted SQL server DB instance from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, ssl, encryption, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL server Enterprise 2016 which is SSL encrypted & I can make the connection working in SSMS & SQL Workbench too, but the problem is when I try the same connection with Oracle SQL developer, the connection is not established & ending up in error.

[Error message (hostname, port & credentials used properly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZfek.png)

But at the same time, when I remove the encryption from the SQL server, I can establish a connection from Oracle SQL developer to the same server without any issue.

I came across a lot of blogs, but I couldn't find right answer for this. As a conclusion, JDBC driver works fine even when the SSL encryption is either configured or not but while using JTDS driver, the connection is not established when the SSL is configured & it works perfectly fine when SSL is disabled.

I need to make the connection working fine with JTDS driver,

so far, the connection string used in JTDS

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DLEXWLABDB01.na.ds.lexmark.com:1433;databaseName=BirthdayDB;ssl=request

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DLEXWLABDB01.na.ds.lexmark.com:1433;databaseName=BirthdayDB;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True
```

Comment: what version of the JDK? what version of JDBC  driver? It's possible you are trying to use an unsupported version of TLS... What version of "Oracle SQL developer"?

Comment: JDBC driver works fine, but when I use jTDS I have this problem & the version or Oracle SQL developer I use is 19.2 & JTDS version is 1.3.1. TLS 1.0, 1.1 & 1.2 all three are enabled.